# vmware esxi - Can't delete directory, not even with rm -rf

Tags: vmware-esxi, rm

I am trying to delete a directory but it's not working.

When using `rm -rf IPCop` I get the error message `rm: can't remove 'IPCop': Directory not empty`.

Another thing I noticed was, when executing `ls` in this directory I get this output: `ls: ./IPCop-cf065eb0.vswp: No such file or directory`. So there seems to be a faulty file entry in it.

How can I delete the directory?

Comment: You can try to see if there are any locks on the files in directory with lsof.

Comment: Just did that. There aren't any.

Comment: what esxi? 5.0? Can you afford rebooting the box? Also which folder did you try to delete with this command? A single VM's folder or the complete datastore folder?
Please provide the full command you ran?

Comment: It's a single VM folder. All other vm-files have been deleted. ESXI version is 5.1

Comment: When you deleted vm-files did you stop that VM?

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but I probably did as I also removed it from Inventory (which is not possible without stopping I guess). I also have this problem in another folder with a `vmware-14.log` file.

Comment: ps -auxwww |grep -i IPCop?

Comment: Why are you messing around at the command line anyway, ESXi isn't a general purpose *nix-based OS, don't treat it like one as it'll let you down if you do. Use it as it's meant to be used.

Comment: @Chopper3 But you know that esxi internally uses the same unix commands?

Comment: Erm...yes, it uses some of them, but with zero guarantees - and it'll be disappearing in a forthcoming release, don't get used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `./IPCop-cf065eb0.vswp` is a broken symlink.  You should be able to remove that using rm, and then rmdir the directory.

However, it's possible that filesystem corruption is also the cause.  This is very annoying in esxi, because there is no fsck for VMFS (the usual solution to this problem if it's not a broken symlink is to reboot in single-user mode and run fsck; this can't be done in esxi for VM partitions).  You could try rebooting the hypervisor, but I am not sure that will fix it; if it doesn't, you'd have to migrate all the VMs off the backing store with the folder in it, and reformat it.

I'd personally suggest that it's not worthwhile to go through all that just to keep things "tidy", though if you suspect a bad disk or frequent power issues might be the cause you should investigate them.

Comment: `rm IPCop-cf065eb0.vswp` results in 
`rm: can't remove 'IPCop-cf065eb0.vswp': No such file or directory`. Rebooting didn't help either.

Comment: You could also try using `unlink` on it if that's available in esxi 5.1 (I forget).  Otherwise, there isn't an easy way to get rid of the file.

Comment: Nope, unlink isn't available. As it exists within 2 folders it kind of bothers me, but having to migrate, format and remigrate is a little much of work I guess.

Comment: Then don't.  Junk files on a vmfs partition have almost no effect.  I really wouldn't bother (see my last paragraph), but you could if you really felt it was necessary.